# Convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1+\cos k}{2+\cos k}\right)^{2k}$. Check my work.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Explore convergence of the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1+\cos k}{2+\cos k}\right)^{2k}$$

---

Using root test: $\sqrt[k]{a_k} = \left( \frac{1+\cos k}{2+\cos k}\right)^2$
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1+\cos k}{2+\cos k}\right)^2 = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left(1- \frac{1}{2+\cos k}\right)^2$$

Now as I understand this limit is not really defined but we know it is between $0$ and $\frac{4}{9}$ and therefore is less than $1$. So by root test the series converges. But is this solution correct?

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks, now I think my solution is not correct but I would like someone can confirm that

Comment: The limit does not have to exist to use the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test). In the most general formulation we use $\limsup$ and that exists and equals $\frac{4}{9}$.